# React Render giving Unexpected Token Error

Tags: reactjs, npm, components

I have two React Apps. One the main app and other is just an app with 1 component. I've imported the component package as node_module using `npm link`. 
Can anyone help me how to solve this?

For the SubApp component the code is as follows:

```
render() {
    return (
      <div>
        External Element.
      </div>
    );
  }
```

And code for the MainApp component is:

```
export default class trial extends React.Component {
    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                <Extern/>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

The error is as follows:

```
../comp/src/extern.js
SyntaxError: /Users/risethi/Desktop/comp/src/extern.js: Unexpected token (13:6)
  11 |   render() {
  12 |     return (
> 13 |       <div>
     |       ^
  14 |         External Element.
  15 |       </div>
  16 |     );
```

This error arises when I try to open MainApp Component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using JSX, which you are, you should not store your files as .js, but as .jsx.

Normal JS files do not allow the usage of HTML elements in their files like that.

Comment: I changed it to JSX. Now I've new type of error.
`You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.` at the same position as of above.

Comment: Ah yes, you are also using something to build the code. Did you tell it to build JSX as well as JS.For example I am building my Typescript with ts-loader.